# Change IDE key xdebug

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug

I want to use xdebug in PhpStorm. However, the IDE key is set to Eclipse, even if I hardcode it in php.ini:

```
xdebug.idekey= PHPSTORM
```

```html
<table>
<tbody><tr class="h"><th>xdebug support</th><th>enabled</th></tr>
<tr><td class="e">Version </td><td class="v">2.4.1 </td></tr>
<tr><td class="e">IDE Key </td><td class="v">XDEBUG_ECLIPSE </td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Comment: And?.. PhpStorm does not really care about IDE key you will be using -- it's just a name/string. You can safely use your current IDE key with PhpStorm. As for the "why it's still `XDEBUG_ECLIPSE` after I have edited it in php.ini" -- it could be: 1) you have edited wrong php.ini (on some setups you may have one ini for CLI and one for web server/Apache) 2) forgot to restart PHP/web server so it can pick up new php.ini?

Comment: In any case: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm (in case you have not seen them yet)

Answer (score 26):

Probably you is using a **Xdebug** extension in your Chrome, so click with the right button to access options, then change this value to **PHPStorm**.

[image]

> The Default Value is Eclipe